# AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strftime'

Tags: python

I've been trying to get today's year, month, and day using datetime. So, I imported the datetime module using `import datetime`. However, I also needed the timedelta command, so I used `from datetime import timedelta`. I'm also using strftime, which I believe is gotten from `from datetime import datetime`. However, I can't run all  of these at once.

So, how can I use the datetime module, with strftime, and timedelta? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "I can't run all of these at once". Why not? And you don't *have to* import them separately, can't you just use `datetime.timedelta(...)` and `datetime.datetime.strftime(...)`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

working with `datetime` gets very confusing once you consider that `datetime` is both the package name *and* a module name inside datetime.

the `datetime` *package* has a lot of different modules, namely:

`datetime` module handles datetime objects.

`date` module handles date objects.

`time` module handles time objects.

`timedelta` module handles timedelta objects.

In your case, when you said `import datetime`, what you're really referring to is the `datetime` *package* **NOT** the `datetime` *module*.

`strftime` is a method of `datetime` *objects* (i.e. under the datetime module)

**therefore, you have 2 ways to go about this.**

If you went with `import datetime`, then you have to specify the package, the module THEN the method, like so:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.now()
today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

or the better, more human readable way is to just import the `datetime` module *under* the `datetime` package by doing a `from *package* import *module*`. Applied to the datetime package, that means: `from datetime import datetime` like so:

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.now()
today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

OR, my preferred method, is to give the module an *alias* (or basically a "nickname"), so it doesn't get confusing (LOL):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta as td

today = dt.now() # get date and time today
delta = td(days=3) #initialize delta
date_you_actually_want = today + delta # add the delta days
date_you_actually_want.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') # format it
```

hope that clears it up for you.

Answer (score 6):

Your error `module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strftime'` suggests that it's not a problem with the imports, but with how you're calling the `strftime()` method.

`strftime()` is a method on the `datetime` class (which confusingly is part of the `datetime` module), so you need an instantiated `datetime` object to call it on. For example:

```
# import datetime class from the datetime module:
from datetime import datetime

# instantiate a new datetime object:
a = datetime(12, 10, 30, 11, 23, 45)

# call the strftime() method on the object:
print(a.strftime("%H:%M:%S %Z"))
# 11:23:45
```